# How can I connect coordinate points on a map using d3js?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm having trouble connecting points with a line on a map using d3. I think that I should use d3.svg.line() to create the points - but when I do it, I simply get a very small blob. Please see the link below for a screenshot of what I've been able to accomplish thus far - I want to connect the black dots with a line. Any help would be much appreciated.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaJJI.jpg)

```
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height*3 + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var group = svg.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")

  var projection = d3.geo.mercator().scale(5000).translate([-2000,5900]) 
  var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection)
  var graticule = d3.geo.graticule()
  var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("linear")
      .x(function(d) { d.geometry.coordinates[0]; })
      .y(function(d) { return d.geometry.coordinates[1] ; });

      // this returns a parse error 
      // .x(function(d) { return projection(d.geometry.coordinates[0]); })
      // .y(function(d) { return projection(d.geometry.coordinates[1]) ; });

  var area = group.append("path")
      .attr("d", path)
      // .attr("d", line(data))
      .attr("class", "area")

})
```

Comment: Don't use `d3.svg.line` for this, use `d3.geo.path`. See the [map tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - when I use d3.geo.path I just get the dots like I currently have. Do you have any other suggestions? Apologies if I'm simply overlooking the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass both components of your coordinate to the `d3.geo.mercator` object, before taking each one separately as your x and y values. Your 'parse error' should go away if you use

```
.x(function(d) { return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0]; })  
.y(function(d) { return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]; });
```

instead. This post has a more complete example: [D3 map Styling tutorial III: Drawing animated paths](http://geoexamples.blogspot.ca/2014/01/d3-map-styling-tutorial-iii-drawing.html).

Hopefully once you are drawing the lines in the correct projection, they'll appear as you expect.